# Swing bind a dialog box to a JButton

Tags: java, swing, dialog

I am trying to bind a new customer menu dialog box to a newCustomer button in my application.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to bind actions in java you add [`ActionListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html)s.

When constructing your button you need to add an ActionListener to it.  That way, when the click event happens, the button knows what to do.

```
newCustomerButon.add(new ActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        // This is where you put the code for popping up the form.
        yourForm.setVisible(true); // Or something similar.
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are several add() methods which are inherited from Component, but none of which will add an ActionListener to a JButton. Do you mean [addActionListener()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)) instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
JButton newCustomer = new JButton();

newCustomer.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        // TODO bind the new customer menu dialog box 
    }

});
```